# use youtube v3 with apikey

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, api-key

I'm trying to use the YouTube v3 API to perform searches using the APIKey instead of the oAuth2.

My problem is that when I use APIKey, the queries always return an error.

This is the code for initializing the service

```
_service = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
[_service setRetryEnabled:YES];
[_service setAPIKey:kAPIKey];
```

and this the code for the query

```
GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForSearchListWithPart:@"snippet"];
query.q = filter;
query.type = type;
query.maxResults = maxResults;

[_service executeQuery:query completionHandler:
 ^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLYouTubeSearchListResponse *searchListResponse, NSError *error)
{
//-- do stuff
 }];
```

The error it returns when using APIKey is the following. if I use oAuth everything goes as expected.

```
error: Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=403 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Access Not Configured)" UserInfo=0x13d10ac0 {error=Access Not Configured, GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x13d0c770: {message:"Access Not Configured" code:403 data:[1]}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Access Not Configured)}
```

I have created the APIKey on the Google APIs Console and the service is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not the ideal solution... but I found a workaround in this post:
[google-youtube-api-v3-ios-app-key-403-error-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440285/google-youtube-api-v3-ios-app-key-403-error-code)

basically, it will work if we use a "Key for browser apps" instead of a "Key for iOS apps".

Comment: I used the commenter's solution. It alarms me that this works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you switch on youtube api from service panel in google-console?

Comment: As I said in earlyer... yes it is enabled :)

Comment: I have worked on searching you tube video list in iphone.but I did not use GLService.I don't know why your API Key is not working.But you can generate another API key from google console.

Comment: I've already generated a 2nd key and the result ended up being the same.