# Assertion failure in -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:]

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-api-objc-client

i am trying to upload a video on youtube using Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C,
I using given below code but it is keep on giving me this error, i tried to run my account on youtube example project here again it gives that same error.

Can any one guide me where is the problem. I check YouTube Data API v3 is on in services page.

```
*** Assertion failure in -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:], /Volumes/data/Work/test/DLNew/DL/google-api-objectivec-client-read-only/Source/HTTPFetcher/GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.m:399
2013-08-30 14:28:31.399 [1250:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unexpected response data (uploading to the wrong URL?)'
```

i check the code of GTMHTTPUploadFetcher class it is crashing the app on this link

```
`#if DEBUG
  // The initial response of the resumable upload protocol should have an
  // empty body
  //
  // This assert typically happens because the upload create/edit link URL was
  // not supplied with the request, and the server is thus expecting a non-
  // resumable request/response.
  NSAssert([[self downloadedData] length] == 0,
                    @"unexpected response data (uploading to the wrong URL?)");
 #endif
```

.

```
 NSString *path              = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MOVIEPATH"];
NSString *filename = [path lastPathComponent];
NSString *mimeType = [self MIMETypeForFilename:filename defaultMIMEType:@"video/mp4"];

NSError *eel=nil;

NSFileHandle *handle        = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path] error:&eel];
NSLog(@"error is  %@",eel);
if (!handle)
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to open file for reading");
    return;
}



GTLServiceYouTube *service      = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
service.authorizer              = self.gTMOAuth2Authentication;

GTLUploadParameters *params     = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithFileHandle:handle MIMEType:mimeType];

GTLYouTubeVideoSnippet *snippet = [GTLYouTubeVideoSnippet object];
snippet.title                   = @"Test title";
snippet.descriptionProperty     = @"Test description";
snippet.tags                    = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"TestOne", @"TestTwo" ,nil];
snippet.categoryId              = @"17";

GTLYouTubeVideoStatus *status   = [GTLYouTubeVideoStatus object];
status.privacyStatus            = @"private";

GTLYouTubeVideo *video2          = [GTLYouTubeVideo object];
video2.snippet                   = snippet;
video2.status                    = status;

GTLQueryYouTube *query          = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForVideosInsertWithObject:video2 part:@"snippet,status" uploadParameters:params];



// Perform the upload
GTLServiceTicket *ticket        = [service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error)
{
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"SUCCESS! %@; %@;", ticket, object);
}];

ticket.uploadProgressBlock = ^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, unsigned long long numberOfBytesRead, unsigned long long dataLength)
{
    NSLog(@"%lld / %lld", numberOfBytesRead, dataLength);
};
```

**----------**

**The problem was i was logging from a new gmail account so i need to login in youtube site and need to create a channel before i can upload video to youtube. So now i can upload videos after creating a youtube channel. but How can i handle this scenario for other users, any idea**

Comment: add some significant piece of code

Comment: uploaded my code for uploading

Comment: you might have to set params.uploadLocationURL = nil;

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue here, I'm trying the service.authorizer solution below but you didn't mark it as an answer. Did you managed to make it work?

Comment: i had left this work and i had not checked, let me know if that works for you then i will mark it as correct answer, thanks

Comment: @Developer , i want to upload a video with resume capability. can you help me on this? (i can't 'Ask Question' any more.) i've done same code as yours.

Comment: @Vats i had not done coding with resume capability. if you had done this please let your thoughts in answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i was logging from a new gmail account so i need to login in youtube site and need to create a channel before i can upload video to youtube. So now i can upload videos after creating a youtube channel. but How can i handle this scenario for other users, any idea

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same crash and find out a solution.
It seems that the client gets this crash also if the underlying request is a bad request but no response information are explicitly provided (my authorizer is valid and passes the check with the method `canAuthorize` as [Ryan_IRL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112243/ryan-irl) pointed out).

After a look at the library I found out that setting the preprocessor macro `STRIP_GTM_FETCH_LOGGING` and enabling the logging for the `HTTPFetcher` somewhere in the code

```
#if STRIP_GTM_FETCH_LOGGING
[GTMHTTPFetcher setLoggingEnabled:YES];
#endif
```

the logs are stored in the `GTMHTTPDebugLogs` folder inside the Simulator (something similar to `/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/65451CDB-27D6-4BE2-910C-7F22D6A01832/GTMHTTPDebugLogs`). There you can find the complete log in HTML format (...).

[image]

Clicking on '*request/response log*' the following log was shown in my case.

```
Response body: (201 bytes)
{
  "id" : "gtl_1",
  "error" : {
    "message" : "Bad Request",
    "code" : -32602,
    "data" : [
      {
        "domain" : "youtube.video",
        "reason" : "invalidTitle",
        "locationType" : "other",
        "location" : "body.snippet.title",
        "message" : "Bad Request"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

the bad request was related to the title (of the video to be uploaded) that was containing some forbidden chars. Fixing the title solved the crash and the video was uploaded correctly. A status 200 in this case is of course... frustrating and clearly wrong.

I'm strongly disappointed also by GTM Library, and by the use of the NSAssert for such situation in the first place.

Comment: As I wrote, with the line `[GTMHTTPFetcher setLoggingEnabled:YES];`. Just put it in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method in the AppDelegate.

Comment: @albertodebortoli Can you please share where you have added this code ?  I'm facing the same issue but the solution is not working. Can you please advice ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you (assertion failure in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.m:399) while uploading a video to YouTube.  I'm posting this in the hopes of saving someone else a few minutes of debugging.

It turned out my problem was old code that set GTLServiceYouTube's APIKey, in *addition* to using OAuth2. Doh.

```
GTLServiceYouTube *youtube = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
youtube.APIKey = @"-my-simple-api-access-key-"; //<-- offending line
[...]
youtube.authorizer = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                 clientID:kYouTubeClientID
                                                             clientSecret:kYouTubeClientSecret];
```

The fix was simply to leave APIKey nil, using only the OAuth2 authorizer.  (APIKey is for 'Simple API Access' only, evidently, any hint of both leads to problems).

Fwiw, the http request succeeded (200 OK), but the http response told a different story. To view the response I added these two lines to the implementation of GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.m (perhaps theres a better way):

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [...]
    NSString *dataStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.downloadedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Downloaded data:%@",dataStr);
    [...]
}
```

The JSON in dataStr:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Access Not Configured",
        "data": [{
            "domain": "usageLimits",
            "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
            "message": "Access Not Configured"
        }]
    },
    "id": "gtl_1"
}
```

Comment: brilliant. Set APIKey to nil fixed the issue. Thanks Moj

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm making an assumption here, but I had the same error as you, and it turned out the issue was actually my authorizer. Make sure you are handling errors with auth, and are applying the auth to the `service.authorizer`.

```
if (![self.youTubeAuth canAuthorize]) {
    // ...
}
service.authorizer = auth;
```

I was also having this issue due to having the wrong scope for the GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch initializer. `@""` will give you better results than the wrong scope. Check the YouTube example app.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to enable Drive API and Drive SDK from the API services tab

Switch the services to on for the project and try again.

If Both are on then make sure you have set the "api_console_project_id" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" argument in your [manifest](https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/source/browse/chromewebstore/manifest.json).

Comment: Both services are on?

Comment: should I enable google drive sdk and api-s for youtube upload too?

Answer (score 0):

I found it from here, [google-youtube-api-v3-ios-app-key-403-error-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440285/google-youtube-api-v3-ios-app-key-403-error-code)

Basically, it will work if we use a `Key for browser apps` instead of a `Key for iOS apps`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if anybody already found the solution for this but here is what I implemented (in Swift) to avoid the app crash:

First check for the Youtube channel status using:

`GTLQueryYouTube.queryForChannelsListWithPart` with part set to "status"

If the value of "isLinked" parameter is not 0 in the response then only upload the video using

`GTLQueryYouTube.queryForVideosInsertWithObject`

otherwise ask user to link youtube channel first.

Answer (score -2):

GTLServiceYouTube *youtube = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
youtube.APIKey = @"-my-simple-api-access-key-"; //<-- offending line
youtube.authorizer = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                 clientID:kYouTubeClientID
                                                             clientSecret:kYouTubeClientSecret];

Comment: It is not working on device,It is working on simulator