# Youtube API V3 IOS error

Tags: android, ios, youtube-api

Similar to this error: [Google YouTube API v3 iOS app key, 403 error code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440285/google-youtube-api-v3-ios-app-key-403-error-code)

**Except in this case Browser key does not work on HTTP requests on IOS and ANDROID.**

I created a Google application in the developers console, turned on "YouTube Data API v3", generated the browser API key, and added my server as allowed referral.

When I run HTTP request like so:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VIDEO_ID&key=API_KEY&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status
```

This works on desktop browsers, but when I try this on IOS or Android, I get error message:

```
There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.
```

Same thing if I go here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

then load video with example id: F08U2yCxbYg , click 'UPDATE PLAYER WITH SELECTED OPTIONS'

It works on desktop browsers but not on ios and android.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with me. To work around I have created a browser API Key. Other people are saying we need to delete the list of bundles IDs because it's a google console bug.